# Applying different css classes for resolutions

Tags: html, css

I have a span class `user-name` inside my UL. I want to either `remove` or `apply` different class on different resolution.

```
<link href="media-queries.css" rel="stylesheet">
<span class="user-name">Shane</span>
```

When i re-define my class on different resolution, it does not `pickup`.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width:480px) {
    .user-name {
        min-width:10px;
        display:inline-block;
        margin-right:20px;   
        color:red;
    }   
}
/* default iPad screens */;
@media only screen and (device-width:768px) {
    .user-name {
        min-width:10px;
        display:inline-block;
        margin-right:20px;   
        color:green;
    }        
}
```

It always pick the base defined class.

```
.user-name {
   min-width:10px;
   display:inline-block;
   margin-right:20px;   
   color:red;
}
```

Comment: Where did you put the "base defined class"? Before or after the media queries? Also, your second media query only works when the screen is exactly 768px wide.

Comment: Its inside the style.css which is before the media-queries.css

Comment: The only different in your style is the color, red againts green. But are you sure your screen is exactly 768px wide?

Comment: No... even the min-width or anything.... are my media queries right?

Comment: Try turning the queries around, first the `768` and then the `480`.

Comment: are you testing this by shrinking the window? if so, device-width isn't picked up. You should try it on an emulator, or a phone.

Comment: @wribit: so if i have to test in browser, what should i use?

Comment: Chrome has a decent emulator built into the dev tools, check it out

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries in proper manner, make sure this code is at bottom

```
.user-name {
   min-width:10px;
   display:inline-block;
   margin-right:20px;   
   color:red;
}

@media (max-width: 768px){ 
   .user-name {
      color:green;
   }
}

@media (max-width: 480px){ 
   .user-name {   
        color:red; /* use can use different color here */
    }  
}
```